# Hadoop File System Task - Error Fail to Copy The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations SSIS to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, ssis

I have following error when using Hadoop File System Task in SSIS. Maybe when  uploading 5 files, 1 or 2 files error like this.

```
Fail to copy E:\Folder\file.csv to /Folder/RAW: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.TryStartWriteSync(Int32 bytesRead)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationService.Hadoop.Common.HttpClientWrapper.Put(Uri uri, HttpContent content, HttpClientHandler handler, Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationService.Hadoop.Common.HttpClientWrapper.SendHttpRequest[TResponse](Func`1 action)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support concurrent IO read or write operations.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginWrite(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.TryStartWriteSync(Int32 bytesRead)
   at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.BufferReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)<---
```